# Placement of participle phrase

Tags: syntax, supplementation, dangling-modifier, participle-phrases

Sentence that may or may not need correction:

> Referred to by some as the "fifth Beatle," `Iain Softley wrote and directed a movie about Stuart Sutcliffe-the original bassist of the group-Backbeat in 1994.`

I'm not sure for this question. Can I please get an explanation for why every choice but the correct one is wrong? Can I have an explanation for the "dash" usage also?

A. Iain Softley wrote and directed a movie about Stuart Sutcliffe-the original bassist of the group-*Backbeat* in 1994

B. in 1994 Iain Softley wrote and directed the movie *Backbeat* about Stuart Sutcliffe-the original bassist of the group

C. Stuart Sutcliffe-the original bassist of the group-was the subject of the 1994 movie, *Backbeat* written and directed by Iain Softley

D. Iain softley, who wrote and directed the movie *Backbeat* about Stuart Sutcliffe the original bassist of the group in 1994

I chose A but the correct answer is C.

Comment: Were the A-D options given to complete the sentence beginning with *Referred to by some as the "fifth Beatle, .."* ?

Comment: yes. they replace the grayish text.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but the dashes look odd to me. I'd think those would be commas instead.  Just a side note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was Sutcliffe, not Softley, who was referred to as the "fifth Beatle".

A participle clause at the head of a sentence is taken to refer to the immediately following nominal—which will almost always be the subject of the main clause.

So if the clause *Referred to by some as the "fifth Beatle,"* remains at the head of the sentence, it must be followed by "Stuart Sutcliffe", to identify its subject—who was referred to in that way.

Only one answer, **C.** has "Stuart Sutcliffe" in that position. Consequently, **C.** is the only answer which satisfies this requirement.